# How to call a function with a parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am training in JavaScript on the TeamTreehouse website, I am stuck on a simple fill in the blank question.

```
function getRandom( upper ) {
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * upper) + 1;
}
```

The fill in part is

`.............;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`getRandom(12)` normally you would add the semi colon but the blank filled that part in.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, its pretty simple:

```
getRandom(12);
```

Comment: Ah sorry, so the proper answer was `getRandom(12)` without the semicolon then?